# What does "expected" and "go with" mean?

Tags: meaning

> The hotel is definitely dated but **it was expected as this building
>   seems to go with the historic look of the neighbouring buildings.**

What does the bold part mean? I know that "expected" means "anticipated" and what "go with" means, but I want to be sure if my understanding is correct. Does the bold part mean:

> the hotel being dated is expected, because there was no difference
>   between this building and other nearby buildings in terms of look
>   (appearance)

I read this somewhere from a review website. It's not clear where I read it because it's been a while. I didn't understand it clearly then, so I wrote it down and I'm asking about its meaning now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. I would say it means that:

> The hotel's appearance being out-of-date was expected because it is consistent with the historic appearance of the neighbouring buildings.

"dated" means out-of-date in this usage (it doesn't mean that the hotel went out on a date, say with a restaurant). This use of "dated" normally carries a negative implication.

"expected' here means "is natural" as much as "is anticipated". The reviewer is saying that what would otherwise be a defect is explained by the style of the neighborhood.

"go with" does not suggest that the appearance is identical to that of near-by buildings, but that in some sense they were in the same or a similar style, that they "fit" together.

You are correct that this seems to be discussing the hotel's appearance, probably its exterior appearance. If one said simply:

> The hotel is definitely dated .

That would suggest a judgement of interior as well as exterior style, and perhaps that it is out-of-date in other ways as well.